# Enable top nav bar for all users, regardless of security groups

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, global-navigation

Ok, we have a Top Nav bar which contains the navigation for all of the site-collection and its sub-sites (and their sub-sites).

[image: NAdmin users see the entire "top nav bar"]

The nav bar looks and works perfectly fine for the site-collection admin(s), since they have access to the entire site-collection. However, when a new user is created, and given access to one of the sub-sites (or sub-sub-sites), that user does not see the top nav bar.

[image: Non-admin users get a limited "top nav bar" view]

I'd like for the top nav bar to be global for *all* users, regardless of what security or group permissions they have.

**Is this possible?**

Details:

- SharePoint Online (Azure)
- SharePoint 2013
- Was created using SPMeta

Comment: Set permissions at the top level, and then set all sub sites to inherit parent site permissions. And then for the sites that only selected users should be able access, break inheritance for those sites and set specific permissions there.

Answer (score 0):

## Set "security-trimming" off

**Global Navigation Security Trimming**
Is the setting used by the SharePoint site-collection which determines whether or not the nav-bar (as well as the quick links bar) is displayed to **all users** regardless of their security group(s).

To update this setting proceed to:

**Site Settings > (Site Collection Administration) Site collection navigation > Security Trimming**

[image: Site Collection Navigation]

[image: Security trimming option]

**Please note:** This applies to the whole site-collection, so use at your risk. Be sure to only disable security trimming only if necessary.